# How to print a long PDF page on a receipt printer?

Tags: windows-7, pdf, printer

I have an Epson TM-T88IV thermal point of sale printer and I print receipts with it. The receipts are given in PDF format. I have the problem that since some weeks the printer can only print receipts with length less then 297mm. Before that he could print any receipt length. Now if I print a receipt with length larger than 297mm it just prints the first 297mm of it and then stops it.

[image]

I guess the problem is an upgrade from Adobe Reader. In the printing settings the layout is set to roll paper  80 x 297mm. If I change it to user-definied size 80 x 3000mm (I have no receipt yet that has this length) then the receipt length is correct, but the width is somehow wrong and doesnt fit on it. Furthermore, I have to change the layout any time to user-defined.

Any idea how I can circumvent the problem such that any length is possible (or that the width does not change) and that I dont have to change the layout type each time I want to print a receipt?

I use Windows 7.

Comment: You haven't mentioned your OS. But there should be other programs that can read + print pdf files.

Comment: Did you try any of the [Epson printer drivers](https://download.epson-biz.com/modules/pos/index.php?page=prod&pcat=3&pid=30)? (Windows might have recently updated those too? Latest release is a few days old.)

Comment: Yes I have installed the most up-do-tade epson printer driver and I have checked it on 2 computers! I also tried to print it with Foxit Reader but it is the same problem as described above.

Comment: Have you tried "fit to printable area" under the "Page Scaling" setting in Acrobat's print dialogue box?

Comment: @hdhondt yes I tried that. The receipt get then scaled on a 80x297mm receipt and it is not readable in my case (since it becomes so small).